# Migrating from "SQL Server" to "SQL Azure, while already using "Linq to SQL"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to migrate an existing application from SQL Server to to SQL Azure. I am using "Linq to SQL". The application is local, what i assume is that i will only have to change the connection string and the application will be connected to the cloud instead of local database and no change is required at code level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have your database migrated to SQL Azure, then yes all you will need to do is change the connection string and open the SQL Azrure firewall to allow your clients to access the DB (this you can do in the portal).

However, while SQL Azure is very close to SQL Server, it isn't exactly the same.  Lots of links to official variations can be found in this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-technical-overview/) or you can try running the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)